# Angular.js Checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to do something very simple with checkboxes and Angular 1.x. I want to pre-select some checkboxes on an edit page and then after some selections are made to save the data to a backend.

I have created this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/roL38ctk/3/

I'm able to pre-select the checkboxes but I struggle to see how the selected items or of any use and could ever be saved to a database, for example after checking and un-checking the options my ng-model might look like this:

```
{"300":false,"400":true}
```

When saving I need to know the ids which have been selected, I have no need or desire to know the state of the checkboxes. Something like:

```
{300,305,310}
```

To me it seems that Angular doesn't handle checkboxes very well without having to hack objects together to extract and massage the data ready for saving.

As a guide I have used http://embed.plnkr.co/g0NMG4rmF4uwzoG2uZhf/preview which I believe is reputable source and claims to be the Angular way? I'm disbelieving that something some elementary can be so taxing when a PHP framework manages this effortlessly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why using a new array ? why don't you set the "checked" property in each of your categories array and bind the checkbox to that ? Something like [this forked fiddle from yours](http://jsfiddle.net/co6g82dy/)

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Thanks but although your fork gives me the ids I can't save the object to my database,without first looping over the object to extract the data. Is it not possible to just have an object of ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put this code in your submit function. You will get values as your expectation:

```
    var arryList=[];
        angular.forEach($scope.selection.ids, function (val, key) {
                        if(val==true){
                    var vd = key;
                    arryList.push(vd);
                    }
                });
 alert(arryList);
```

Or you can use angularjs material checkboxs [Check here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox).

It's third demo already satisfy your requirement.

Comment: I marked this answer as the solution because a third part library is required, although I chose to use Checklist-model as it is a bit lighter- one file required. Angular Material seemed to me to be a little heavy with 4 files required and gave a horrible ui

Comment: If you used angularjs ui routing then ui would not heavy because all library load just once to whole session.